# cordova-plugin-ad-admob via phonegap build,unable to load and show ads

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am using this plugin: https://github.com/cranberrygame/cordova-plugin-ad-admob

Hi, I'm a total newbie - just to warn you, my level of understanding beyond javascript/html is minimal and I have no native experience. I'm building through the phonegap build service.

I have the plugin loaded onto my phonegap app.

it's building okay, I've checked that.

In the javascript it's setting all the bannerAdUnit+interstitialAdUnit+rewardedVideoAdUnit+isOverlap+isTest variables correctly

it doesnt throw up an error doing the

```
window.admob.setUp(bannerAdUnit, interstitialAdUnit, rewardedVideoAdUnit, 
isOverlap, isTest)
```

but using try-catches to alert me, it's throwing up errors with:

```
window.admob.preloadInterstitialAd();
window.admob.showInterstitialAd();
window.admob.preloadRewardedVideoAd();
window.admob.showRewardedVideoAd();
```

because i'm doing all the build through phonegap (i have zero android native experience or knowledge) all i know is that there is an error, but not where it's coming from.

Does anyone have any pointers as to where the issues might be coming from, things i could try to rule out?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Plug your phone into your computer and use Chrome Inspect.

Answer (score 1):

I advice you not to use third party plugins for services like admob/in-App Purchase.

use official admob plugin for cordova/phonegap. https://github.com/admob-google/admob-cordova

It is easy and well documented.

Comment: That's not much good for me as I need rewarded video and beyond calling itself 'admob google' it doesn't seem very official.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by:

1) adding an explicit reference to cordova.js in my index.html

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

and also I had to remove my content declaration

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
```